# Reverse Number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I'm trying to reverse random int in JavaScript. I'm using this code:

```
'use strict';
function reverse_a_number(n)
{
    n = n + '';
    return n.split('').reverse().join('');
}
print(reverse_a_number(+gets())); //**+gets()** is like scanner.nextInt in Java and **print();** work's like console.log(); in JS.
```

This work well if number are not a big integer.

For the first test in my judge, code works correctly:

```
Input   Output
256     652
123.45  54.321
```

But for BI i get Wrong Answer:

[image]

Maybe the best way is to cast array to string... Any suggestions?

Comment: Your function seem to work. What input gives you a bad output?

Comment: repl.it sample would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you cast your `get()` input to number. Don't do this, use a string as, I think, you receive it. Example:

```
'use strict';

function gets() {
  return '52387456983765.98364593786'
}

function reverse_a_number(n)
{
    n = n + '';
    return n.split('').reverse().join('');
}


console.log(reverse_a_number(+gets())); // "489.56738965478325"


function reverse_a_number_new(n)
{
    return n.split('').reverse().join('');
}

console.log(reverse_a_number_new(gets()));  // "68739546389.56738965478325"
```

To read more about floats in JS: https://javascript.info/number#imprecise-calculations

Comment: More of an IEEE 754 issue than a JS issue, but I think your solution is correct for the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverseNum(n){
    var reverse = 0
    while(n!=0) {
        var rem = n%10
        reverse = reverse*10 +rem
        n = parseInt(n/10)
    }
    return reverse
}

reverseNum(523)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.